# Adding to a column in MySql using .where method for a rails validation/comparison

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble adding to a column in MySql using a .where method for the purpose of comparing. Here is the following code:

```
        def find_conflicting(event, location, room_ids, start_time, end_time, exclude_statuses = [LOST])
        return [] if room_ids.blank? || start_time.blank? || end_time.blank? || location.blank?

        full_room_ids = location.room_dependencies(*room_ids.map(&:to_i))
        o = joins(:rooms).where{ (rooms.id >> my{full_room_ids}) & (status << my{exclude_statuses}) }.group('events.id')
        o = o.where( :event_start.lt => (end_time + event.teardown_time.minutes), :event_end.gt => (start_time - event.setup_time.minutes) )
        o = o.where{ id != my{event.id} } unless event.nil? || event.new_record?
        o.to_a
        end
```

The jist is that I am trying to find conflicting events. Except when I try to convert event_start (which is a dateTime object) into a time, then add time to it much like the following line of code:

```
(end_time + event.teardown_time.minutes)
```

I keep on getting the following error:  Mysql2::Error - Unknown column 'event_start.time' in 'where clause. Any idea on how to add time on it for the comparison? I understand the error, as say event_start.time is not a column, but all I am looking for is adding time just for a comparison. Any and all help is appreciated. Cheers~

Comment: The error is at `event_start.time`. In MySQL, `event_start.time` means to get `time` column from `event_start` table, which isn't really what you want. So apparently `event_start` is NOT datetime object according to your error. Show me your code block that contains `event_start.time`.

Comment: o = o.where{(event_start.time + 60.minutes < my{end_time + event.teardown_time.minutes}) & ((event_end) > my{start_time - event.setup_time.minutes})}